# Where to declare PHP before passing to JavaScript via JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Well, I can successfully fetch a result set from a MySQL database via PHP, and display its contents on a web page via HTML.

I can also write JavaScript functions.

Here's the problem: I have no idea *where*, physically, I need to put my PHP code to have the array result set show up in my JavaScript functions!

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php

    $photos = array();
    [code to fill this array with results from database]

?>
```

I have this directly under the head. Also under the head:

```
<script>

    prevPhoto() {

        var jPhotoArray = <?php echo json_encode($photos); ?>;

        for (var i = 0; i < jPhotoArray.length; i++){

            if (thePhoto.src == jPhotoArray[i]['photo']) {

                if (i + 1 != jPhotoArray.length) {

                    thePhoto.src = jPhotoArray[i + 1]['photo'];

                }

            }

        }

    }

</script>
```

(For the curious, the intended functionality is to create a manual slideshow of photos that users can flip through by clicking "forward" and "backward" for as long as there is another picture behind the one currently displayed.)

But when I launch the page and take a look at the memory, the variable jPhotoArray is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get from var_dump($photos) done right before you try to output into JavaScript.

Comment: When you do get this working, I suggest you move all your JS to the bottom of the page. It doesn't need to be in the head. You can also give a slight boost (depending on the size of your generated data) by using AJAX to get the JSON object after the page is done loading.

Comment: @colepanike Your suggestions do not apply universally.  If you are going to make these statements, please explain *why* so that those who aren't aware can learn when and when not to use your suggestions.

Comment: @Brad excellent point. My suggestions are specifically to boost page performance, or rather _perceived speed_. By putting the script tags at the bottom of the page you allow the browser to first render the HTML and CSS, then process your JS. This allows the user to observe progress. The AJAX method further boosts this perception by allowing you to place a 'loading' icon (or some other processing indicator) on the page while the data is fetched and then used, you can also omit the progress indicator.

Comment: This is generally accepted _good practice_, though as Brad points out it's not ideal in all situations. One such situation would be if your object is very small, at some point it's faster to just inject the code directly. @Brad if you'd care to elaborate on other less than ideal situations, or if I've gotten this wrong please don't hesitate to correct me.

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't know or care where it exists when mixed with output.  All that happens is PHP is executed, then anything not in a PHP block is sent to the output buffer, then more PHP is executed if there is another PHP block.

In your case, all you need to do is put data in your `$photos` array before you get down to your `<script>` tag.

If it isn't working, something else is wrong.  Use `var_dump()` to ensure that `$photos` has anything in it first.  Chances are, your problem is elsewhere in your code.  Also, always view the source of your HTML to see what that assignment line actually has in the output.

Finally, as a matter of code style, it is best to get all of your application logic done before you output anything at all.  Separate the concept of the *view*, outside of that application logic.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you actually forgot the function keyword in front of `prevPhoto()`. Have you tried simply logging the outcome of the php array? For example by adding     `echo "console.log(\"".$photos."\")"`    I've also found the following post that will probably answer your question: [how to assign php array values to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813580/how-to-assign-php-array-values-to-javascript-array)