# How to display images on hover in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfWyN.png) **HTML**

I want to display above images on hover the below images. but I can't get the idea how to display it why because i am new to angular

```
<div class="col-md-7" ng-controller="slideController">
    <div class="text-center">
    <?php 
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE product_id ='$id' ");
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>
            <img src="../backend/uploads/<?php echo $row1['image']; ?>" width="200px" height="300px" ng-model="id[<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>]" ng-hide="hideImage">
    <?php } ?>
    <hr>
    <?php 
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE product_id ='$id' ");
        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) { ?>
            <img src="../backend/uploads/<?php echo $row1['image']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" ng-mouseover="slideImage(<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>)">
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var slide=angular.module("myApp",[])
slide.controller('slideController', function ($scope) {
$scope.id = {};
$scope.hideImage = true;
console.log($scope.id)

$scope.slideImage = function(id) {
    if (id == $scope.id) {
        $scope.hideImage = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to output backend data as javascript object, and then act on that object in angular.

```
<div class="col-md-7" ng-controller="slideController">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img ng-repeat='image in images' ng-src="{{image.url}}" width="200px" height="300px" ng-hide="!image.show">
    <hr>
      <img ng-repeat='image in images' ng-src="{{image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px" ng-mouseenter="image.show = true" ng-mouseleave="image.show = false">
    </div>
</div>

<script>var images = [
  <?php 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM product_images WHERE product_id ='$id' ");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
  {
    url: "<?php echo $row['image']; ?>",
    id: <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
  },
  <?php } ?>
]</script>
```

---

Edit: I see you are trying to use the center area as main viewer like a carousel. In this case it is better to assign a variable instead of using `ng-repeat`.

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('slideController', SlideController);

function SlideController($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    { id: 1, url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/17/09/36/domestic-cat-726989_960_720.jpg' },
    { id: 2, url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/03/21/20/kittens-555822_960_720.jpg' },
    { id: 3, url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/09/29/12/38/cat-188088_960_720.jpg' },
    { id: 4, url: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/15/20/21/cat-1044750_960_720.jpg' },
  ]
  
  $scope.mainImage = $scope.images[0];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-7" ng-app="test" ng-controller="slideController">
  <div class="text-center">
    <img ng-src="{{mainImage.url}}" width="200px" height="300px">
    <hr>
    <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image.url}}" width="100px" height="100px" ng-mouseenter="$parent.mainImage = image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BhaskararaoGummidi This should be the correct answer, I am withdrawing mine, since its not the correct approach. But also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813580/how-to-assign-php-array-values-to-javascript-array)

Comment: @Icycool I think the array loaded is invalid since there is no comma in between the objects of the array, can you change this, I found this link for loading into array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813580/how-to-assign-php-array-values-to-javascript-array), Thanks, great answer!

Comment: @Icycool  the Array will have a comma in the last element of the array is that fine? Can you provide the complete JS for the  angular array, it should be a scope variable, sorry the answer is incomplete so I am asking this, also first element should be shown by default

Comment: @NarenMurali yes i always use js array with comma in last element for version control purpose, so it's fine. If you want to show first element by default, you can set `$scope.images[0].show = true` in the controller.

Comment: @Icycool Excellent sir......but once mouseleave the image the default image disappearing.

Comment: @BhaskararaoGummidi Edited for different requirement

Comment: @BhaskararaoGummidi Updated. Need `$parent` inside `ng-repeat`