# How To Store PHP Array In Javascript Array And Display?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, arrayiterator

I've tried using json_encode to store a PHP array as a javascript array, but when I try to display the javascript array or reference an index of it, it shows as empty or undefined.

What I basically want to do is take four different PHP arrays ($lids, $dates, $prices,  $scaledPrices) and combine them into one array so that each element of this new array contains the corresponding index from each of the original four arrays (i.e. new_array = [[5001, 2020-01-01, $100.00, $110.00], [5002, 2020-01-021, $103.45, $103.23], . . . ]

I'm able to successfully use the MultipleIterator feature to correctly combine the four PHP arrays as this display correctly, but I can't seem to then store this in a javascript array. Any suggestions?

[how to assign php array values to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813580/how-to-assign-php-array-values-to-javascript-array)

```
// initialize php arrays to populate and use for chart
$dates = array_column($priceData, 'date');
$scaledPrices = array_column($priceData, 'scaledP');

// arrays used for chart must be reversed and json_encoded
$chart_dates = json_encode(array_reverse($dates));
$chart_scaledPrices = json_encode(array_reverse($scaledPrices));

// initialize $lids and $prices arrays to use for download
$lids = array_column($priceData, 'lid');
$prices = array_column($priceData, 'price'); 

// combine $lids, $dates, $prices, and $scaledPrices into one array
$csv_lids = new ArrayIterator($lids);
$csv_dates = new ArrayIterator($dates);
$csv_prices = new ArrayIterator($prices);
$csv_scaledPrices = new ArrayIterator($scaledPrices);

$csv_data = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC);
$csv_data->attachIterator($csv_lids);
$csv_data->attachIterator($csv_dates);
$csv_data->attachIterator($csv_prices);
$csv_data->attachIterator($csv_scaledPrices);

// this correctly loops through and displays the new array
foreach ($csv_data as $item) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($item);
    echo "</pre>";
}

?> 

<!-- store php csv array as javascript array variable -->
<script>
    // var js_csv_data = new Array();

    var js_csv_data = <?php echo json_encode($csv_data); ?>

    // this shows as an emtpy object . . . even without JSON.stringify
    console.log(JSON.stringify(js_csv_data));
    // this shows as undefined . . . even without JSON.stringify
    console.log(JSON.stringify(js_csv_data[0]));
</script>
```

Comment: what happens if you simply `console.log(js_csv_data)`? can you post the output?

Comment: console.log((js_csv_data)) just outputs an empty object. but I'm going to try the suggestion from Cubakos below

Answer (score 1):

The `js_csv_data` shows as an empty object because `$csv_data` is an object of type `MultipleIterator`, which is "actually" an empty array.

You can check this using a `var_dump()` on `$csv_data` (or pretty print the dump with: `highlight_string("<?php\n\$csv_data =\n" . var_export($csv_data, true) . ";\n");`

which will show you this:

```php
<?php
$team =
MultipleIterator::__set_state(array(
));
```

The `MultipleIterator` objects, only iterate over all attached iterators and the actual data are only accessible when you iterate over the object.

So, in order to pass all the data as json, you should gather them first in an array. You already have the loop, so, just make the following additions:

```php
// Init data holder array
$all_csv_data_arr = [];

// this correctly loops through and displays the new array
foreach ($csv_data as $item) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($item);
    echo "</pre>";
    
    $all_csv_data_arr[] = $item;

}
```

Now, in the javascript part, you should use `JSON.parse` to parse your data, which will be in the form of an array of arrays:

```js
    var js_csv_data = <?php echo json_encode($all_csv_data_arr); ?>
```

EDIT:
<s>`console.log(JSON.parse(js_csv_data));`</s>
`JSON.parse` is not needed as the `js_csv_data` already contains a well formatted JSON obejct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and explanation Cubakos. I am able to console.log just js_csv_data and correctly see the array of arrays as desired. Is it still necessary to use JSON.parse?

Comment: Well, yes it is necessary to use `JSON.parse` to the `js_csv_data` because as it is right now, it is a JSON string which you can not do much about with it.  If you try to access the contents of `js_csv_data ` like try writing `js_csv_data[0]` in the console, and you will see that you are not getting the table data you want. In order to actually be able to access the table data, you will have to first parse the JSON string. e.g. `var js_csv_data = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($all_csv_data_arr); ?>);`. Then trying again `js_csv_data[0]` in the console will return you the first array data.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for the help Cubakos.

Comment: I'm testing with this but I keep getting this error. Any idea why?

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 4
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at group.php?FID=16:231

```
<script>
    var js_csv_data = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($csv_data_arr); ?>);
    console.log("test");
    console.log(js_csv_data);
    console.log(js_csv_data[0]);
</script>
```

Comment: it's strange that when I take off the JSON.parse it displays fine (both the entire array and the array at index 0).

```
    var js_csv_data = <?php echo json_encode($csv_data_arr); ?>;
    console.log("test");
    console.log(js_csv_data);
    console.log(js_csv_data[0]);
```

Comment: Ohh, I messed up my test file! I was accidentally using `json_encode` two times on the php array, resulting in a JSON string. 
I'm sorry for the confusion. You are absolutely right! 
You do not need to parse the data, since they are already a JSON Object!